# Swift: Webview reload when a tabItem is pressed in TabView

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to Swift. I have a hybrid app with 5 tabs made with TabView.

When tap on any tabItem (URL loads in webview) this works fine

Clicking on any link in the webView works fine

My problem is this:

When clicking any link in either of tabItems, the WebView goes to another page of the website which is not listed in the tabItems. I need these tabs clickable even when I am in the page and reload the webview to the initial URL.

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var selectTab = "0"

var body: some View {

TabView(selection: $selectTab){

Home()

.tag("0")

.tabItem(){

Image(systemName: "house")

}

AllListings()

.tag("1")

.tabItem(){

Image(systemName: "key.horizontal")

}

CreateListings()

.tag("2")

.tabItem(){

Image(systemName: "plus.circle")

}

Agencies()

.tag("3")

.tabItem(){

Image(systemName: "person.line.dotted.person")

}

Projects()

.tag("4")

.tabItem(){

Image(systemName: "building.2")

}

}

.tint(.white)

}

init() {

UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.lightGray

}

}
```

I have tried multiple ways but none was helpful.

Comment: Not lot of code about your web view but may try to load the original url in .onAppear of the views in tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please show me how can I use onAppear with tabItems? As I said, I'm new to Swift, I don't have any experience in it.